# Opencv naive image match

Tags: opencv, image-processing, fft, emgucv

I'm using OpenCV/EmguCV to perform a naive matching procedure. I've two images, img1 and img2, and I enumerate the translations and rotations of img1, and match against img2 to find the optimal matched difference.

Here's the code

```
        for (int dx = -img2.Width / 2; dx <= img1.Width - img2.Width / 2; dx++)
            for (int dy = -img2.Height / 2; dy <= img1.Height - img2.Height / 2; dy++)
                for (float r = 0; r < 2 * Math.PI; r += 0.1f)
                {
                    var img2r = img2.Rotate(r, new Gray(0));
                    img1.ROI = new Rectangle(Math.Max(0, dx), Math.Max(0, dy),
                        (Math.Min(dx + img2r.Width, img1.Width) - Math.Max(dx, 0)),
                        (Math.Min(dy + img2r.Height, img2.Height) - Math.Max(dy, 0))
                        );
                    img2.ROI = new Rectangle(Math.Max(0, -dx), Math.Max(0, -dy),
                        (Math.Min(dx + img2r.Width, img1.Width) - Math.Max(dx, 0)),
                        (Math.Min(dy + img2r.Height, img2.Height) - Math.Max(dy, 0))
                        );

                    var diff = img1.AbsDiff(img2);
                    var avg = diff.GetAverage();

                    img1.ROI = new Rectangle();
                    img2.ROI = new Rectangle();
                }
```

So my questions are

1) Do we have a built-in function to do this, For efficiency concerns?

2) How to perform a "sub-pixel" level of this matching?

3) Can we harness fft to accelerate the match to O(nlogn) by converting into frequency domain?

## Note

cvMatchShape() won't make it because I'm doing naive matching. The two images are quite similar.